# How to find out SQL Server default instance name?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three SQL server instances on my computer. How can I find out which is the default one?

```
var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=SampleDb;Integrated Security=True")
```

I want to learn when I use '.' as above which database I will use.

Comment: The "." indicates the default local instance.  Local named instances can be accessed by specifying ".\<instance-name>".  The default instance may be accessed locally or remotely using "<host-name-or-ip-address>".  Named instances can be accessed locally or remotely using "<host-name-or-ip-address>\<instance-name>" or "<host-name-or-ip-address>,<port-number>" specifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have more than one instance per OS installation if all of them have different instance names. The data source property has the format

```
HOST\INSTANCENAME
```

You are connecting to the default instance (of which there can only be one).